# Change device for WIFi hotspot

Tags: wireless

I have two WiFi adapters installed and I wish to use the second one for my mobile hotspot instead the the first one. How do I do this? I tried using nm-connection-editor to change the device but when I turn on mobile hotspot it just creates another connection with the first device.

Comment: Try using `nm-connection-editor` with your hotspot connection profile, first tab, and set `Automatically Connect` with a priority of 1. Set the device, as you have been. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

***Note: not tested because of no availability of two wifi-cards/ adapters in my laptop..***

get the wifi-cards/ adapters names by running `lshw` command and look for the required values.. Identify the wifi card 1 & 2 in your case and note down the logical names

some of the contents of `lshw` in my System

```
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 3165
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
```

Here for example the second Wifi card/ adapters logical name is `wlp2s0` and we want to use this connection for `wifi-hotspot`

Create a Wifi-Hotspot connection with below command..

```
nmcli device wifi hotspot ifname wlp2s0 con-name PARROT password 1234abcd
```

change `wlp2s0` with your wifi cards logical name
change `PARROT` with what ever connection name you wish to
change `1234abcd` with what ever password you wish with minimum 8 characters

to turn on and off this Wifi-Hotspot use below commands, change `PARROT` with your connection name

```
nmcli connection up PARROT
nmcli connection down PARROT
```

from `man nmcli`

```
wifi hotspot [ifname ifname] [con-name name] [ssid SSID] [band {a | bg}] [channel channel]
   [password password]
       Create a Wi-Fi hotspot. The command creates a hotspot connection profile according to
       Wi-Fi device capabilities and activates it on the device. The hotspot is secured with
       WPA if device/driver supports that, otherwise WEP is used. Use connection down or
       device disconnect to stop the hotspot.

       Parameters of the hotspot can be influenced by the optional parameters:

       ifname
           what Wi-Fi device is used.

       con-name
           name of the created hotspot connection profile.

       ssid
           SSID of the hotspot.

       band
           Wi-Fi band to use.

       channel
           Wi-Fi channel to use.

       password
           password to use for the created hotspot. If not provided, nmcli will generate a
           password. The password is either WPA pre-shared key or WEP key.
```